# How can I split a string containing one or more escaped newline character?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string containing \n (`\\n`) and \n\n (`\\n\\n`) (escaped newlines).

I would like to split like this:

```
'a\\na'.split(/\\n+/)
> [ 'a', 'a' ]
'b\\n\\nb'.split(/\\n+/)
> [ 'b', 'b' ]
```

But I don't how to apply `+` for the `\\n`, because in my example is applied only to the `n` and I get `[ 'b', '', 'b']`

I've tried grouping: `(\\n)+` or `(:?\\n)+` but it does not seem to work.

Comment: That doesn’t look escaped. Did you mean `'a\\na'`?

Comment: If you have a sequence that you want to quantify, wrap it with a group: `/(?:\\n)+/`

Comment: you could replace the \n with another character, then split the string. e.g. `'a\na'.replace("\n","_").split("_")`

Comment: @Ryan Yes I mean 'b\\n\\nb'. I wrote this because in console.log appears as 'b\n\nb'. Why did you mark as offtopic, it is js and regex?

Comment: @charisz: “off-topic” is kind of a Stack Overflow oddity; the actual description is underneath it: you just had a typo, `:?` vs. `?:`. Those get closed because they’re too case-specific, but that doesn’t mean it’s a bad question, don’t worry =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re correct that you need a non-capturing group to avoid extra entries from `split`, but the syntax is `(?:`, not `(:?`.

```
'b\\n\\nb'.split(/(?:\\n)+/)
```